# ignite-native-base-boilerplate - Clicking on Explore Button on LaunchScreen throws error - Android

Tags: react-native, boilerplate, native-base

Can anyone please help with following issue?

After creating app using:

ignite new appname --max --boilerplate native-base-boilerplate

Click on Login - successfully navigates to LaunchScreen
Click on Explore - throws following error

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.routeName')

C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-navigation\src\routers\createConfigGetter.js:51:10
render
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-navigation\src\views\Drawer\DrawerView.js:190:6

C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1863:19
measureLifeCyclePerf
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1610:15
_renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1862:54
_renderValidatedComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1872:34
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1696:57
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
mountChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2871:62
initializeChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2940:45
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2969:84
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
mountChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2871:62
initializeChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2940:45
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2969:84
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
mountChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2871:62
initializeChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2940:45
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2969:84
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
mountChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2871:62
initializeChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2940:45
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2969:84
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
mountChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2871:62
initializeChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2940:45
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2969:84
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
mountChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2871:62
initializeChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2940:45
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2969:84
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
mountChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2871:62
initializeChildren
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2940:45
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2969:84
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
performInitialMount
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:54
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:184
mountComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:53
mountComponentIntoNode
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1998:50
perform
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1382:99
batchedMountComponentIntoNode
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2004:24
perform
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1382:99
batchedUpdates
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2077:139
batchedUpdates$1
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1456:61
renderComponent
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2032:45
render
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:3258:46
renderApplication
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\renderApplication.js:34:4
run
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:117:10
runApplication
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:191:26
__callFunction
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:266:47

C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:103:26
__guard
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:231:6
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
C:\Users\usr\Documents\play\appname\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:102:17

Answer (score 0):

This is a react-navigation bug react-community/react-navigation#3148. You can fix it by pinning react-navigation to beta 21.